# Как работает Comparator в Java

Tags: java, compare

Читаю Хорстмана Java 8 издание. В одной из глав используются статические методы интерфейса `Comparator`. До дженериков еще не дошел, но примерно понимаю что это. В этом интерфейсе есть метод `comparing`:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Не могу понять как он работает. Что значит возвращаемый методом тип:

```
<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T>
```

и в операторе `return`, это приведение к типу, или еще что?

```
(Comparator<T> & Serializable)
```

Было бы хорошо, если кто-то мог объяснить построчно, что происходит в этом методе.

Comment: Сравнивает один объект с другим. Если не дошли до джинериков, то это не поймете.

Comment: @terence да, `(Comparator<T> & Serializable)` - это приведение к типу. Для меня это тоже стало откровением, хоть джаву вроде как думал что знаю неплохо)) Ссылка на место в спеке: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(...)
```

1. `Comparator<T>` - возвращаемый параметризованный тип, где `T` - параметр заведомо неизвестного типа, но во время выполнения будет известен. Данный параметр объявлен в следующей записи: `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>`, поэтому далее в внутри метода можно использовать параметр типа `T`.
2. `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>` - объявляет два типовых параметра: первый - `T`, второй - `U`. Параметр типа `U` может быть любым типом, наследующим `Comparable`. `Comparable` в свою очередь может быть параметризован любым типом, который не выходит за границы `U`. Получается параметр `U` может быть любым типом между `Comparable` и `U`.

Answer (score 0):

- Function keyExtractor функция берёт обьект класса T или его суперкласс (не спрашивай почему не субкласс) извлекает ключ класса U или его субкласс
- Метод возвращает функцию класса Comparator которая сравнивает обьекты T по их ключам U
- (Comparator & Serializable) каст типов к первому и второму интерфейсу... хм, хотя метод сам возвращает только Comparator  поэтому второй каст без толку
- U extends Comparable U это такое "сравнимое", что может быть сравнено с каким-то своим суперклассом.
- 

> но во время выполнения будет известен.

во время выполнения ничего не известно так как  в Java стираются типы. И ещё, опять таки из за этого можно не заморачиваться с типами. Метод .compareTo выполнится в зависимости от того какой в действительности это обьект с его создания,  а не от того какой у него сейчас каст.

Comment: нет, второй каст не без толку. Из джавадоков к Comparable: _It is generally a good idea for comparators to also implement java.io.Serializable, as they may be used as ordering methods in serializable data structures (like TreeSet, TreeMap). In order for the data structure to serialize successfully, the comparator (if provided) must implement Serializable._

Comment: но comparing  возвращает только Comparator

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16. Исходя из этого, если мы кастуем лямбду к `java.io.Serializable`, то она автоматически становится `implements Serializable`...